jGit get ObjectId's of conflicting file
I use jGit and the status() command to list the conflicting files.
I want to load the two versions of a file in status CONFLICTING, and solve the conflict by myself. OpenAI suggested the code below.
But the method dirCache.getEntry() does not longer accept two parameters, but only one:
dirCache.getEntry(filePath). How can I fix the code?
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Status;
import org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache;
import org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheEntry;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class JGitConflictObjectIds {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Repository repository = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setGitDir(new File("/path/to/repo/.git")).build()) {
            Git git = new Git(repository);
            Status status = git.status().call();

            Set<String> conflictingFiles = status.getConflicting();
            for (String filePath : conflictingFiles) {
                DirCache dirCache = repository.readDirCache();
                DirCacheEntry ourEntry = dirCache.getEntry(filePath, DirCacheEntry.STAGE_2);
                DirCacheEntry theirEntry = dirCache.getEntry(filePath, DirCacheEntry.STAGE_3);

                ObjectId ourId = ourEntry.getObjectId();
                ObjectId theirId = theirEntry.getObjectId();

                System.out.println("File: " + filePath);
                System.out.println("Our version ObjectId: " + ourId.name());
                System.out.println("Their version ObjectId: " + theirId.name());

                String ourContent = readFileContent(repository, ourId, filePath);
                String theirContent = readFileContent(repository, theirId, filePath);

                System.out.println("Our version:\n" + ourContent);
                System.out.println("Their version:\n" + theirContent);

            }
        }
    }


    private static String readFileContent(Repository repository, ObjectId commitId, String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
            TreeWalk treeWalk = TreeWalk.forPath(repository, filePath, revWalk.parseCommit(commitId).getTree());
            ObjectId blobId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
            ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(blobId);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            loader.copyTo(out);
            return out.toString();
        }
    }
}
}


The premise is broken. Just the 2 tips of a file to know what they should like in a merge is impossible. You need to consider a common ancestor (the closer, the better) to figure out the merge result.

Does this mean that I can solve a conflict by myself only directly after merge, using the MergeResult? No other way?
